# What's the right excel formula or VBA code to copy a pattern and paste?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

So I have the following requirement:

**Sheet 1**

```
xxxx
YYYY
ZZZZ
```

**Sheet 2**

```
1994 xxx
1995 xxx 
1996 xxx
1994 YYY
1995 YYY 
1996 YYY
1994 ZZZ
1995 ZZZ 
1996 ZZZ
```

Essentially what I want is to copy company names from sheet 1 and paste them against each given year and repeat for almost 600 companies.

Is there is any formula or VBA codes to get this done? I would really appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your list of companies and use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range.

This will open the Power Query Editor. You will see something like this:

[image]

Use Home>Close & Load

Now we're going to take a moment to create a dynamic list of years between a starting and ending year. This will be useful if you want to change the start and end later.

Enter the starting year and ending year in separate cells in your workbook.

[image]

Select the starting year, then name the cell by typing a name like start_year in the Name Box:

[image]

After you have named the cell, select the cell and use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range

After the Power Query Editor opens with a single cell with a column header of Column1, right click that cell and choose Drill-down:

[image]

If you expand the Queries pane on the left, you will see this:

[image]

Use Home>Close & Load To and select Only Create Connection.

Repeat this for the end year, so that you have this:

[image]

Again, Close & Load To and Only Create Connection.

Now, in Excel, click Data>Queries & Connections. You should see this:

[image]

Mine says '50 rows loaded', because I created dummy data with 50 company names. Yours may be different.

Right-click the Table1 query and choose 'Edit'. This will open the Power Query Editor again.

Now go to Home>Advanced Editor. It should look like this:

[image]

We're going to add some code to create that list of years.

Add this line to line two:

```
years = List.Numbers(start_year,end_year),
```

Like this:

[image]

Now click Done. It will look like nothing has changed, but don't worry.

Use Add Column>Custom Column and configure it like this:

[image]

When you click OK, you'll see this:

[image]

Click the double-arrow at the top of the year column and click 'Expand to New Rows'

[image]

You'll see now that you have a row for every combination of Company and Year:

[image]

Use Home>Close & Load to put this back into your workbook.

If your list of companies or the starting and/or ending year changes, you can just change the source data and refresh this query.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and tried so but instead of limiting to one comapny to the year range the output result keeps adding years to infinity. Do you have any input on this ?

Answer (score 0):

That's a very easy thing to do. Lots of ways, but the following is the simplest that fits what you just described.

Total up how many company names there are. (Just press `Ctrl-Down Arrow` in the column of them and see what row is the last row. Use the first row with one of them and that to see how many exist. Say it's 587 for the sake of this answer.)

On the other sheet, Pick a column and enter the first year, then copy that down to fill a total of 587 cells. Say you start in A1 and end in A587. In cell A588, enter the formula `=A1+1`. Copy that down to fill another 587 cells. Do it by copying the cell, then highlighting it and the rest of the 587 cells (A588:A1174) and paste. So now you have all 587 cells highlighted and filled with the formula. Copy that block and press `Ctrl-Down Arrow`, then `Down Arrow` again to reach the next empty cell (A1175).

Now paste again, and move down to the next empty cell. Continue until you have a 587 cell block of all the years you care to have listed. Highlight the whole column of entries (perhaps that was 30 years so you're highlighting cells A1:A17610). Copy the whole bunch and `Paste|Special|Values` to change it all to permanent text.

Go copy the 587 company names and paste them in the next column from B1:B587. Then go to the next empty cell, B588, and enter the formula `=B1`, then copy the cell. Move to column A and go to the very last filled cell, or just use `F5 GoTo` to go to cell B17610 (last cell with years is A17610, and you really want to be in column B anyway). However you do it, get to B17610. Press `Shift-Up Arrow` to cover all those empty cells (itself and all the way up to A588 which is where that will take you... it's OK to paste over A588 'cause it's the same formula).

Once highlighted, paste. Then highlight all the column B cells like you did with column A, then copy and `Paste|Special|Values` to make them also all permanent text.

That only looks like an hour and a lot of hassle. In fact, I'd expect 2 minutes at most, even if you bumble around some. And if you don't... however it looks reading it, it's fast in real life.

Done.